# Whonix problem: Wallet Address Changed, Coins Lost

Tags: address, wallet-recovery, tor

Hi I am new to crypto and I am still learning the basics of things. I hope somebody can help me understand what's going on with this problem I am struggling with for the past many hours.

I installed Monero CLI on Whonix. I created a wallet just fine. Somebody sent some coins to the wallet address. But I had to synchronize the wallet before the coins show up. No matter what i tried I could not connect to the daemon through Tor ( I kept getting "could not bind IPv4 /failed to initialize p2p server" error). I search for a long time for a solution to this, but I could not solve it.

Eventually I gave up on Whonix. I said I will figure out anonymity later, I just want to see my coins. I went to a different machine and installed the Monero wallet GUI  on clearnet (no Tor). I used the seed to recover my wallet. Got the daemon working and synchronized the wallet. I thought the coins I received before would finally show up in my wallet....... but they don't. I checked and realized that now my wallet receive address is completely different from before. I exchanged coins at the new address to make sure it works, and sure it does..... but the coins from my initial transaction never arrive in the wallet.

I used blockchain explorer and saw the first transaction went thru to the old address and it's getting broadcasted. I went back to Whonix machine (daemon still cant connect so it still cant synchronize the wallet) and the wallet still shows the old receive address from before I recovered the seed on the 2nd machine (as expected). Which means the coins are sitting in a wallet somewhere...?

My questions:

1. Why did the wallet address change? Are they 2 separate wallets now?
2. Can I ever get the coins from the first transaction? Or are they lost forever

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

A Monero mnemonic seed is a word based representation of a secret spend key. It is essentially the secret spend key. If you use the same set of words, you will end up with the same secret spend key, which deterministically yields the same public spend key. Since you have a seed in the first place, your secret view key is also deterministically derived from that seed (it is possible to have independent view and spend keys, but you don't get a seed for those). In turn, this deterministically yields the public view key. Both public view and spend keys deterministically yield your standard address. So from a seed, you get an address.

Note that some software (mostly trezor and ledger I believe) don't do this, but you did not mention you use those so I'll assume you don't.

So the most likely explanation is that you did not restore the same seed. Make *really* sure you copied the seed correctly from the first machine to the restoring machine. If you're *really* sure you used the same seed and the addresses are still different, then you could copy the keys file (if you name your wallet BLAH, then the keys file will be named BLAH.keys) to the new machine and open it without restoring from seed. Then file a bug on https://github.com/monero-project/monero and includes details like your monero software version, whether both machines are 32 bit, their architecture, and anything else that seems relevant.

If you keep the keys file, you should be able to see and use your monero whenever your p2p connection gets fixed. The keys file contains the secret keys (which are another representation of the seed).